# Map of maps and custom allocator

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any way to use a custom allocator with a map of maps?

I.e let's say I have:

```
typedef std::map<int,int> Inner;
typedef std::map<int, Inner> Outer;
```

Can I have a custom allocator for both?

How can I do that since I cannot define the allocator for the inner map in the constructor of the inner map?

I.e for the outer I would do:

```
Allocator myAllocator;
Outer outer(std::less<int>(), myAllocatorObject);
```

For the inner??

Comment: Can you not write an allocator for the outer `map` wherein `construct` specifyies the allocator to the inner `map`s?  (I haven't tried personally, but this seems a promising prospect).

Comment: Not sure I understand how to do this. Example?

Comment: This demo does something very similar to what you're describing (so it demonstrates the principle even if you don't actually want to use boost):  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers_of_containers

Comment: The allocator is part of the type, so you need to change the typedefs, not just pass a different argument to the constructor.

Comment: The outer map definition does not cause any inner map objects to be constructed, so no inner allocator is needed there. You would specify the inner map allocator when constructing inner map objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this:

```
typedef std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, SimpleAllocator<std::pair<const int, int>>> Inner;
typedef std::map<int, Inner, std::less<int>, SimpleAllocator<std::pair<const int, Inner>>> Outer;
Inner inner;
Outer outer;
```

I've tried some sample code here and it works:

http://ideone.com/CuoaiQ

---

The very nice remake version by Jonathan Wakely:

http://ideone.com/wBtaks

Comment: An alias template makes the declarations much simpler: http://ideone.com/wBtaks (Also your allocator constructors should not be `explicit`, there's no need to put `inline` on members defined in the class body, and you are including way too many headers for that program. It should also be possible to make your allocator much simpler but ideone.com is stuck at GCC 4.8 so it doesn't work there)

Comment: ah, you're right, I copy-paste some codes from my sample code project so it looks messy. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Thanks that will work. But what if I want to initialize the SimpleAllocator myself?

Comment: I think you can just pass the allocator object into `map`'s ctor, like `explicit map (const allocator_type& alloc);` you can check here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/